# Separate string in Python

Tags: python, regex

Guys I know that I already asked for a very similar but I'm going crazy.....

I have a string:

```
string = '☕ Drink the  ❶  best  ☕coffee☕'
```

And I expect this:

```
string = ['☕', 'Drink', 'the',  '❶',  'best',  '☕', 'coffee', '☕']
```

Comment: Have you tried to match alphabets and other `non-space` characters?

Comment: Have you tried something except for expecting?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service!!

Comment: Yes, this has been asked many times. Maybe the same `[a-zA-Z]+|\S` will work for you, too.

Comment: it doesnt work man...

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Be specific.

Comment: I ask because the only difference between this question and your previous one is that this one has capital letters, and it is extremely trivial to add capital letters to the regex, so if there's something else happening, you should tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = [el for el in re.split('([\W+])', '☕ Drink the ❶ best ☕coffee☕') if el.strip()]
print(s)
```

output:

```
['☕', 'Drink', 'the', '❶', 'best', '☕', 'coffee', '☕']
```

Comment: Dear God thx for sending me neverwalkaloner....!

Comment: @dapo you are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ord` to find the ordinal of a character. If it's higher than 126, it's somewhere above ASCII, in Unicode territory.

```
import itertools
s = '☕ Drink the  ❶  best  ☕coffee☕'

for k,v in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: ord(c)<127):
    for word in ''.join(v).split():
        print(word)
```

Result:

```
☕
Drink
the
❶
best
☕
coffee
☕
```

Note: I wrote this to a file, as terminals often have poor Unicode handling:

```
>>> with open(r'theoutput.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as output:
...     for k,v in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: ord(c)<127):
...             for word in ''.join(v).split():
...                     print(word, file=output)
...
>>>
```